# vertical align Image Block at middle

Tags: html, css

I need to align image at the middle of the page. I used margin:auto to align middle horizontally.

How do I align the div block middle vertically. I have below conditions to follow.

1. I can not mentioned width and height of div or image.
2. I can not use margin-top in pixels.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/cDD7m/).

Comment: This is a common problem. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing it almost right. Here's your fixed fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/cDD7m/4/

The thing is, you need an element with `display: table` wrapping one with `display: table-cell` for the table-cell to behave like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Will background image technique fit your needs?

```
background: url(my-image.jpg) center center no-repeat;
```